# Trying to create a tweet with an image using tweepy Client API V2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to create a tweet with an image using Tweepy Client (https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet) and unfortunately I haven't managed to success. I've tried with older version API but it asks to have elevated access.

Currently I can only send a normal tweet doing the following:

```
  client = tweepy.Client(
        bearer_token=self.__bearer_token,
        consumer_key=self.__consumer_key,
        consumer_secret=self.__consumer_secret,
        access_token=self.__access_token,
        access_token_secret=self.__access_token_secret
    )
  
  client.create_tweet(
            text="Here there is my tweet"
            )
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user in Twitter community web answered this question:

It looks like you have essential access, if so then you can only use API v2 and can’t use v1.1 yet, while the media upload endpoint is not yet available in v2.
Reference:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/integrate#media